# Using hash function as a string length compressor for a spam detection system. bad idea?

Tags: php, hash

I'm planning to use **`ripemd128`** to make a hash of my users posts and store it on the db, something like this:

```
function shortener($a){
    $a = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $a);
    $a = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $a);
    $a = substr($a,(round(strlen($a) * .25) - 1),round(strlen($a) * .50));
    return hash('ripemd128', $a);
}
```

The hashes will have a total count column and will increment each time a user posts something with that same hash. if it reaches lets say 10, all succeeding posts with that same hash will be tagged as spam.

I want to use **`ripemd128`** because:

1. The hash it produces has a **`word size of 32`** and user posts will have a word size of 200 - 3000.
2. It has **`No Collisions`**

according to this [**wiki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

This is not the main function of **`ripemd128`** but it fills the need. My question is would it be ok to use it for this purpose? if not, why and could you give an alternative approach. thanks

Comment: Via the pigeonhole principle, all hash functions exhibit collisions (given enough distinct inputs).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth so I guess bad idea for this purpose?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The chance of collision in a 2^128 hash-space is astronomically small.  That said, if you have a real spam problem, then as soon as the spammers realise what's going on, they'll just make sure each post is slightly different (e.g. append a random character).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes I figured that would happen that's why I'm thinking of getting a specific string pattern after `substr` (Something like character positions `1-8-3-5-20-13-16`) before running it through the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I love the idea but it is far simpler to just:

(pseudo code)

find user who posted post

check db for that users posts and see if any posts are identical

- unless your site is MASSIVE you will not see much over-head with this as you can do a straight $newpost == $oldpost comparison.

Misunderstood question - edit as below:

To allow for quick check of repeat posts across all users I would suggest the following:

As user posts take first 32 char and last 32 char of post (assuming post > 32 char -> if not all char) and check against 2 new fields in db with the first 32 and last 32 char of post in 2 columns.

If one or both matches then do full post comparison.

Comment: yes. but the problem is that some users have multiple accounts. So limiting it to per user will not have a big effect on preventing spam.